# How Can I Select One or More column Asp.Net Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to choose one or more columns something like this but I m taking error.

```
List<Uye> allCustomer = new List<Uye>();
allCustomer = db.Uye
    .Select(i => new Uye { Ad = i.Ad })
    .ToList();
```

`The entity or complex type 'tasarımDesenleriOdev1.Models.RepositoryPatern.Uye' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.`

This is my `Uye` table.

```
[Table("Uye")]
public partial class Uye : BaseEntity
{
    public Uye()
    {
        Order = new HashSet<Order>();
    }       

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Ad { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Soyad { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string KullaniciAdi { get; set; }

    [StringLength(500)]
    public string Foto { get; set; }

    public int? YetkiId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Sifre { get; set; }

    public string Adres { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Order> Order { get; set; }

    public virtual Yetki Yetki { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: we will need you to post your full definition for entity Uye to help with this one.

Comment: Your code is correct. It should't cause such error type

Comment: I edit my post . Can u check please ?

Comment: Are you actually meaning to use `.Select`? Perhaps `.Where` with a clause would be better? Or if you're looking for all of the records, simply remove the `.Select` portion altogether. `.Select` is typically used when you only want specific columns from your dataset.

Comment: What is the intention of your code? Why do you need `Uye` objects only with `Ad` values set?

Answer (score 1):

The exception information you provided ...

> The entity or complex type
>   'tasarımDesenleriOdev1.Models.RepositoryPatern.Uye' cannot be
>   constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

... seems to reflect the fact that you are trying to construct new instances of your complex entities when perhaps you should be just selecting without new or to a new DTO type rather than to an entity type.

try something like ...

```
var allCustomer = db.Uye
    .Select(i => new { 
        Ad = i.Ad, 
        Soyad = i.Soyad 
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I tried  var  allCustomer = db.Uye.AsEnumerable().Select(i => new Uye { Ad = i.Ad }).ToList();                                                                                            
 As Enuerable method now it s giving this error                 
 DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>.

Comment: you don't want to call `AsEnumerable()` there anyways, it will just force EF to get all the Uye entries immediately and the Select afterwards will drop most of the data you just pulled across the network from sql.

Comment: @Serkan it is not possible to get that exception from the line of code in my example, please provide a MVCE ... I was assuming from the question tags that you are using EF, you seem to be implying a problem with datasets now.

Comment: Out of curiosity what happens when you do ... var items = db.Uye.ToList();

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding , if you want to just select a column from your object you can simply use like below:

```
List<Uye> allCustomer  = db.Uye.Select(i => i.Ad).ToList();
```

**Note:** 
I hope in your table Uye ,Ad is one of the column. If so then the above linq query should surely work

Additional info:http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/linq/difference-between-select-and-selectmany-in-linq

Kindly let me know your feedbacks or thoughts

Thanks
karthik

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you do not need to construct `Uye` instances manually, EF does that work for you when you need it. In this case it looks like you want all the `Ad` column values from table `Uye`. The code below should work correctly as long as your entity relationship is configured correctly:

```
allCustomers = 
    db.Uye
        // notice we create an anonymous object. EF uses this to figure out
        // exactly what you want selected in your sql SELECT field list, in 
        // this case it should end up with SELECT Ad from Uye...
        .Select(uye => new { uye.Ad })
        // force EF to generate an run the sql and materialize the results
        .ToList();
```

If you wanted the entire list of Uye objects because you needed all the column values, you could just do:

```
allCustomers = db.Uye.ToList();
```

If you needed more than one column, but not the entire object, you can just add more columns to the anonymous select like this:

```
allCustomers = db.Uye
    .Select(uye => new { uye.Ad, uye.Property1, uye.Property2, ...})
    .ToList()
```

Comment: Thank u ! I change my query like this select(i=> new {}) now its working

Comment: @Serkan Isn't that what War suggested earlier? Are you sure you typed his in properly?

Comment: Yeh I was thinking ... Eh, Mike repeats my answer that was "wrong" but it's now somehow right? What changed?

Answer (score -1):

try code:

```
allCustomer = db.Uye
.Select(i => new Uye { Ad = i.Ad ,Soyad =i.Soyad })
.ToList();
```

Comment: Your answer was flagged as low-quality because it is too short. Please expand on your answer. Maybe explain why this would be a better way to do it and why the way the OP was trying to do it didn't work.